# How we can create List of GString in groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

```
ArrayList<GStringImpl> a= ["gaurav " , "ashish"];

println a;
```

here it gives an error when we used [`GStringImpl`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GStringImpl.html).

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Did you import import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl first?

Comment: yes i have added it , but still it doesn't find GStrinImpl class

Comment: why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works in groovy 2.4.3:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

ArrayList<GStringImpl> a = ["gaurav " , "ashish"]
println a
println ''

def b = "hello"
println b.class.name
println b
println ''

def c = "worl${100 as char}"
println c.class.name
println c
```

yielding

```
[gaurav , ashish]

java.lang.String
hello

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
world
```

Your code should work with `import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work for me. Actually, as I know, static definition in groovy is bad idea, it works, but slowly. But if it really needed you can try to  do it like this:

```
List<GString> list = []
```

or this

```
def list = [] as ArrayList<GString>

def list = new ArrayList<GString>()
```

Comment: it returns the class java.lang.String while I required org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

Comment: most likely you can't create list of GStringImpl because:

  Default implementation of a GString used by the compiler. A GString
  consist of a list of values and strings which can be combined to
 create a new String.

Comment: You can use code listed above and put in list your GStringImpl instance without any generics..